# LinkedIn Follow Company Plugin gives X-Frame-Options error

Tags: linkedin-api

Since short my "Follow Company Plugin" for LinkedIn is not working anymore.
I was using following code:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: nl_NL</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="84769" data-counter="right"></script>
```

I was going back to the plugin generator on the site:

[LinkedIn Follow Company Plugin Generator](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company)

But it seems that the Preview over there is also not working anymore and is giving me the same error:

> Refused to display 'https://www.linkedin.com/cws/followcompany?companyIdentifier=1337&counterPo…ass%3Dmiddle-center&token=&isFramed=true&lang=nl_NL&_ts=1439398136529.7654' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Did anybody else have the same issue? On the site they said they track "linkedin" tagged issues. I was wondering if they did a breaking change in the API or if I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same issue here since yesterday.
I have contacted the support on Twitter and they just told me to go here...

EDIT : Problem is now solved.... no idea why and how.

Comment: Yes the same over here, probably a bug in their API. Thanks for the feedback, will put yours as answer.

Comment: Any idea for that issue ?